# NoSQL Connections node in TALEND not found

Tags: nosql, talend

am trying to create a new connection to Mongodb via Talend etl tool, the thing is i can't find the NOsql connection node in the metadata section in repository, this is what my metadata looks like

[image]

this what it should look like , but i can't seem to find it in my talend

[image]

do anyone know how can i add it ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the **Talend Open Studio for Bigdata** edition to have these components (they are not included in the **Talend Open Studio for Data Integration** edition).

See https://community.qlik.com/t5/Design-and-Development/Not-able-to-see-NoSQL-connection-in-Talend-Open-Studio/td-p/2362855